# Mysterious find command hogging memory on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems, linux-mint

I'm running linux mint 17 and I notice that every so often my computer slows to a crawl.W When I look at top I see "/usr/bin/find / -ignore_readdir_race (..." etc. sucking up most of my memory. It runs for a really long time (several hours) and my guess is that its an automated indexing process for my hard drive.

I'm working on a project that requires me to have over 6 million audio files on a mounted SSD so another guess is that the filesystem manager is trying to index all these files for quick search. Is that the case? Is there any way to turn it off for the SSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `locate` command reports data collected for its database by a regular cron task.  You can exclude directories from the database, making the task run more quickly.  According to [updatedb.conf(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/updatedb.conf)

> **`PRUNEPATHS`**
> A whitespace-separated list of path names of directories which should not be scanned by [updatedb(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb). Each path name must be exactly in the form in which the directory would be reported by locate(1).
>
> By default, no paths are skipped.

On my Debian machine for instance, `/etc/updatedb.conf` contains this line:

```
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media"
```

You could modify your `/etc/updatedb.conf` to add the directories which you want to ignore.  Only the top-level directory of a directory tree need be listed; subdirectories are ignored when the parent is ignored.

Further reading:

- [Tip of the day: Speed up `locate`](https://majewsky.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/tip-of-the-day-speed-up-locate/)
- [How do I get mlocate to only index certain directories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160424/how-do-i-get-mlocate-to-only-index-certain-directories)

Answer (score 1):

It's a daily cron job that updates databases used by the locate command. See `updatedb(8)` if you want to learn more. Having six million audio files will likely cause this process to eat up a lot of CPU as it's trying to index your local filesystems.

If you don't use locate, I'd recommend simply disabling updatedb, something like this:

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
sudo chmod -x /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
sudo mv /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db.bak
```

If all else fails just remove the package.

Comment: updatedb is I/O-bound, and it doesn't do anything CPU-intensive.  Perhaps on a fast-enough SSD it could keep one core fairly busy, but definitely not on a hard disk.